# Android studio shows error after importing my project

Tags: android-studio

I am very new to android studio and development. I have imported my project into the android studio and it shows the below error.

> Error:(20, 0) Unable to load class
>   'org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException'. Possible causes
>   for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache
>     may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>     timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync
>     project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build
>     process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve
>     this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
>     (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party
>     plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project
>     or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the
>   case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and
>   then killing all Java processes.

Can any one help me out to resolve this

Comment: Did you try the things mentioned in the error message?

Comment: i tried first 2 and it does not work out. I did not get the Third point and what can be dont for that.